# Computing fft2 of an image in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, computer-vision, fft

[image: go_dark.jpeg]
[image: results of the transformation]

I am experimenting with Fourier transformations and the built-in NumPy.fft library. I was trying to see the difference between computing just fft2 of an image and fftshift on fft2 of an image. But for some reason, I am not getting the results that I was expecting. I have tried changing images as well but regardless of what I use, I get the same results as below. If someone could help me out here, it would be awesome. This is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage, fftpack

light = cv2.imread("go_light.jpeg")
dark = cv2.imread("go_dark.jpeg")

g_img = cv2.cvtColor(dark, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
di = (np.abs((np.fft.fft2(g_img))))
dm = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(g_img)))


plt.figure(figsize=(6.4*5, 4.8*5), constrained_layout=False)
plt.subplot(151), plt.imshow(di, "gray"), plt.title("fft");
plt.subplot(152), plt.imshow(dm, "gray"), plt.title("fftshift");
plt.show()
```

Comment: What results do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: I am trying to locate zero frequencies and observe how fftshift moves them to the center. Basically, I am trying to visualize the before and after of zero frequencies in my image once fftshift is computed. I read that 2d-fft places the origin in the 'beginning' but I haven't been able to locate it. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I still don’t know what you are seeing nor what you expect to see. Displaying the frequency domain like that likely results in one pixel being white and the rest nearly black. Play around with intensity scaling in the plot. Best display is using logarithmic mapping of the intensities.

Comment: Also, use a smaller image, then you can see the individual pixels.

Comment: Try to plot on a logarithmic scale

Answer (score 1):

`di` and `dm` are floating point values.  Matplotlib can't do that.  First, try `di.astype(np.int8)`.  However, many of the values are out of range.  You may need to scale the array.

Comment: I’m pretty sure it can.